# Why is data of the query result, and refetch's result not equal in apollo client?

Tags: reactjs, apollo, apollo-client

I was having synchronisation issues with using apollo client queries the traditional way. Using `useEffect` when `data` changes, and make my actions was causing flashing screens, so I decided to use a different scenario:

```
  const [initGetItems, { refetch: refetchItems, data, loading }] =
    useGetItemsLazyQuery({
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    });
  const getItems = (variables: GetItemsQueryVariables) =>
    (!data && !loading
      ? initGetItems({ variables: variables })
      : refetchItems(variables)
    ).then(({ data }) => {
      return data?.getItems || [];
    });
```

to *promisify* a lazy query, and make state changes at the same time with the data. I'm storing the items in react state, which is more reliable for my case.

There's a case though in my app where the `data` is changed from outside of `getItems`, by `refetchQueries` after a mutation. I have to update my react state with the new result, but the state currently is set by `getItems`. My idea was to compare the react state of items with the `data.getItems`. I would expect that the object references are equal, but they are not. If we extend the above code like:

```
  const [items, setItems] = useState<GetItemsQuery['getItems']>([])
  const [initGetItems, { refetch: refetchItems, data, loading }] =
    useGetItemsLazyQuery({
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
    });
  const getItems = (variables: GetItemsQueryVariables) =>
    (!data && !loading
      ? initGetItems({ variables: variables })
      : refetchItems(variables)
    ).then(({ data }) => {
      setItems(data?.getItems || [])
      return data?.getItems || [];
    });
  console.log(items, data?.getItems, items === data?.getItems);
```

`data?.getItems`, and `items` are never equal. I'm not sure how apollo client works behind the scenes, but I would expect the `data` returned as a promise is the same as `data`, from the second part of the tuple returned by the query hook especially because the results are cached.

When I do the console log, the objects inside the array (seem) equal.

Am I doing something wrong, or shouldn't expect the two `data`s to be equal?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is that you're comparing the memory address of the variables and not the contents of the variables. Because you're going to call getItems on every re-render, that address will change every re-render. It's not clear what's going on inside those functions; but you could look into using the `useRef` hook to save state inside the `current` property and compare those values across renders.

This type of thing is generally pushed into a useEffect() with dependencies on the bits that can change.

Comment: `getItems` is not running on every render, it runs in my case for pagination, but you could imagine it's only running on a button click. It's only for demonstration purposes. And `getItems` function is in indirect relation with the query, so if that function runs, the `data` of the query will change as well. I know that I'm comparing the object references, but I'd expect that internally apollo returns the same `data` in the promise, and as the hook's result as well. I cannot use `useEffect` because of the reason mentioned, and `useRef` is not really for my case.

Comment: I want `data.getItems` to be different from `items` (in react state) if it's triggered by `refetchQueries` from a mutation, but the same if it's triggered from `getItems` if it makes sense.